# Dynamically adding and populating select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically add and populate some select boxes:

```
$("#mydiv").append("<table id='myTab'><tr></tr></table>")
var row = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    row += "<select id='sel" + i + "'>";

    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        row += "<option id='opt" + j + "'>Test " + j + "</option>";
    }

    row += "</select>";

    $("#mydiv").on('change', '#sel' + i, function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
}

$("#mytab").append(row);
```

Unfortunately, the select boxes won't be displayed.
However, when I output `row`, I get the expected output:

```
<select id='sel0'>
    <option id='opt0'>Test 0</option>
    <option id='opt1'>Test 1</option>
    <option id='opt2'>Test 2</option>
    </select>
<select id='sel1'>
    <option id='opt0'>Test 0</option>
    <option id='opt1'>Test 1</option>
    <option id='opt2'>Test 2</option>
</select>
<select id='sel2'>
    <option id='opt0'>Test 0</option>
    <option id='opt1'>Test 1</option>
    <option id='opt2'>Test 2</option>
</select>
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/watd4uya/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/watd4uya/3/

Comment: @gurvinder372: Doing so, you can see a small rectangle, so the table remains empty, I guess?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace ...

```
$("#mytab").append(row);
```

... with ...

```
$("#myTab").append(row);
```

---

#### Demo

```js
$("#mydiv").append("<table id='myTab'><tr></tr></table>")
var row = "";

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    row += "<select id='sel" + i + "'>";

    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        row += "<option id='opt" + j + "'>Test " + j + "</option>";
    }

    row += "</select>";

    $("#mydiv").on('change', '#sel' + i, function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
}

$("#myTab").append(row);
```

```css
table {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">

</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/watd4uya/4/))

Answer (score 1):

Append the select boxes inside the `<td>` instead of `<table>`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. just selecter is misspelt.

```
$("#myTab").append(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), ony you need to update the data.